# Combine two model managers for a queryset

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to apply a custom model manager to a QuerySet produced by the default model manager?

I need to filter a QuerySet using the default model manager, since I have a M2M through model, and it is easiest to do the filtering there rather than increasing the complexity of my custom manager by an order of magnitude: this filter looks as follows:

```
talent_set = UserProfile.objects.filter(positions=Position.objects.get(position=filter))
```

I then need to apply my custom model manager to this filtered query, like so:

```
final_talent_set = UserProfile[filtered].custom_manager.do_something()
```

Is there a way to do this, or a different approach I should take? Perhaps a way to append a column (from the custom manager) onto the end of the default manager? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, why not just use the same `filter` in `get_query_set()`?

I mean:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MyManager, self).get_query_set().filter(
            positions=Position.objects.get(position=filter)
        )

    def do_something(self):
        q = self.get_query_set()
        # do something
```

Comment: Silver_Ghost: great thank you. And how do I pass the variable "filter" to the MyManager? How to I call the main model form the view? And how would I call the custom manager from the main model? Thank you.

Comment: Variables can be passed to `do_something()` method but in this case `filter` should be called in `do_something`:
    
    def do_something(self, filter):
        q = self.get_query_set()
        q = q.filter(Position.objects.get(position=filter))

Comment: Silver_Ghost: and how would I call it from the view passing the filter 'writer' -- i.e., the equivalent of: `UserProfile.custom_manager(filter='writer').do_something()` ?

Comment: `UserProfile.custom_manager.do_something(filter='write')` should work.